# Is there any tab manager for visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

It's common for me to have 20+ files opened in Visual Studio *(I use VS 2008 now, but we will migrate to VS 2010, soon.)*. **Is there any add-in which could help organize actively opened files?**

I mean something like [Firefox colorful tabs](http://rockyourfirefox.com/2010/09/colorfultabs/) or a tab-manager which will group windows tabs by projects or folders,...

Comment: I am rolling back changes made to my question, because you removed information that I still use VS 2008.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com) document tabs manager add-in (developed by me) supports VS 2010+ and VS 2008.

Comment: I really liked tab studio, i used the trial. Unfortunately I think the price of USD 49 is too high for some of us outside US. My company would never invest in add-ons and I have bought a few add-on from my own pocket. I understand you have solid reasons to price it the way it is, but if it's something like USD 15 but for only 1 year license usage, I'm in! I have bought add-ons that cost usd 10 - usd 20. Lastly, great plugin!... really love it during the trial period. Going back without tabs studio makes me really miss it everyday.

Comment: I think Sergey would actually get more profit if he lowered the price. I really like Tabs Studio, but 50 USD is just too much for me personally.

Comment: Damn, if only it were ~$25, Power tools it is.

Comment: $49 is too much for something that just groups a few tabs together. Don't get me wrong, it does a *wonderful* job of what it does, but it doesn't do much. It's not 1/3 as useful as ReSharper, but it's 1/3 of the price. Sorry chum, too hot for me. Shame cos it's a cracker. If only there was a free version that did nothing more than the similar-name tab grouping.

Comment: Agreed - liked the demo, but it's just not worth the purchase for how little it actually does.  Too bad.

Comment: The Power tools should be a first answer because they are free and also do the job

Answer (score 13):

[Visual Studio Power tools will do it for 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/), out of luck for 2008 (as far as I know).

There are versions of Power tools for all the newer Visual Studios.
Newest: [VS Power tools 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d)

You can have them color coded by assembly, most recently used up front, and several other sorting/grouping options

Comment: Thanks for this tip. Although "VS Power tools" is powerful and free, the Tab Studio proposed by Sergey seems to be better solution for my problem. It supports VS 2008 and it shows multiple rows of tabs at once.

Comment: @taylonr is this working with VS207 Community? I cannot find any relevant info. and I cannot install it. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I like the alternative approach proposed by the 'Tidy Tabs' extension.

Rather than providing you with a mechanism to manage billions of tabs, it helps by automatically monitoring and cleaning up your tabs to only display the ones that you have most recently been using.

It's free too. :)

From the extension page:

> Tidy Tabs keeps your document well organized by closing tabs that are no longer being used. Tabs that have not been viewed in a configurable amount of time can be closed with a keyboard shortcut (CTRL+ALT+ESC) or closed automatically whenever you save a document.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b80ab284-83f8-4022-bc78-95af126ba5f0